# Display text in cell if text is not present in row above

Tags: tables, macros, longtable

I'm working on making a style for writing theatre scripts, and I have the code below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcommand{\newLine}[2]{\textbf{\uppercase{#1}}&#2 \\}

\begin{longtable}{l p{\textwidth}}
    \newLine{Hussein}{Hello.}
    \newLine{Hussein}{``Hussein'' should not be beside this line.}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

This code provides this:[image: What code above provides]

I want to make it so that the `\newLine{}` function (at row 2) can determine if "Hussein" is in row 1 column 1, and if the text matches, don't display it on row 2.

I hope anyone can help me with this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcommand{\newLine}[2]{%
  \def\thisName{#1}%
  \ifx\thisName\lastName\else\textbf{\uppercase{#1}}\fi
  \gdef\lastName{#1}&%
   #2 \\}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{l p{.75\textwidth}}
    \newLine{Hussein}{Hello.}
    \newLine{Hussein}{``Hussein'' should not be beside this line.}
    \newLine{Someone}{Hello}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution worked great.